# MySql, Counting multiple groups, and creating a view

Tags: mysql, sql, count, subquery, sql-view

I have data that has a logical grouping that I can assume, but I haven't been able to figure out how to make the view properly for my needs. I do not own the data provider, and am only reading the database. I have no control over what is being provided, I just need to provide some counts

---

Logic Map

```
name like "TL-3%" = MGrid_N53

name like "TL-P1%" = MGrid2_MGrid

name like "TL-P2%" = MGrid_MGrid2
```

and so on, (10 groups)

I would like to create a view that says something like
(route would be = to the mapped logic above, IE MGrid_N53)

```
select route, 
   (select count(*) 
    from table_name 
    where name like "Tl-3%"), 
   (select count(*) 
    from table_name 
    where name like "TL-3%" and source is not null)
```

The 1st column is the router being used. the 2nd column is total routers available, the 3rd column indicates how many are used.

The problem Im having is I can't figure out how to do this, for each route, with the logic mapping involved, without building 10 subqueries for each router.

Is there any cleaner way to do this? If there is more data needed I will provide.

The data will be updated every 10 seconds, at which point a view should be updated with the used/total counts for the router. I only care about the counts, not the data itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
select (case when name like 'Tl-3%' then 'MGrid_N53' 
             when name like 'TL-P1%' then 'MGrid2_MGrid'
             . . .
        end) as route,
       count(*) as num,
       count(source) as num_withsource
from table_name
group by route;
```

Comment: The problem Im having is route is not an actual value, it is a logic jump from data I have, that I can assume. IE route = MGrid_53, IFF name = "TL-3%"

Comment: You got it so quick, I can't even accept the answer yet. You sir are the man